# Best practice for button resizing in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know the best practice for button resizing in Boostrap 3.

My code is:

```
<a href="" title="" class="btn btn-header btn-block btn-lg hidden-xs">Bonus</a>
<a href="" title="" class="btn btn-header btn-block btn-sm visible-xs">Bonus</a>
```

I think this method generates too big file size if I duplicate every line. So, maybe I can override the `btn-lg` class in media queries. What do you think? Is there any 'official' practice?

Comment: Do you want a smaller button officially

Comment: Yes, I would like a smaller button on small devices.

Comment: Do you want a responsive button re-sizing depending on screen resolution

Comment: Is much better to define media queries for all buttons instead duplicate html elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to eliminate duplicate markup, you could use CSS media queries instead and scale the button size accordingly..

Working demo: http://bootply.com/128288

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {}    
@media (min-width: 768px) {}
@media (min-width: 992px) {}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```